# textarea losing newlines when using disabled or readonly

Tags: html, google-chrome

In Chrome 67.0 (Mac), when specifying a `readonly` or `disabled` attribute on a `textarea` element, newlines seem to be stripped out when rendered. Removing the attributes correctly formats the content.

For example, without `readonly` or `disabled`:

```css
textarea {
    height: 100px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea-badge1">&lt;div class="_wv_widget"&gt;
    &lt;a href="https://www.google.com" title="This is a link"&gt;
    &lt;img src="" alt="" title="" /&gt;
 &lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</textarea>
```

With `readonly`:

```css
textarea {
    height: 100px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea readonly id="textarea-badge1">&lt;div class="_wv_widget"&gt;
    &lt;a href="https://www.google.com" title="This is a link"&gt;
    &lt;img src="" alt="" title="" /&gt;
 &lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</textarea>
```

With `disabled`:

```css
textarea {
    height: 100px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea disabled id="textarea-badge1">&lt;div class="_wv_widget"&gt;
    &lt;a href="https://www.google.com" title="This is a link"&gt;
    &lt;img src="" alt="" title="" /&gt;
 &lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</textarea>
```

Is there a solution for this? Using \t doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you change `white-space: nowrap;` to `white-space: pre-wrap;`? This seems to work for me.

Comment: Not working on Chome 74. :\ Anyway I want to prevent wraping in the textarea which this change precludes.

Comment: Are you sure? Just tried the original code and it's still working fine for me, check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/385atsgy/

Answer (score 4):

Setting `white-space: pre` will produce the desired result.